# Failing to setup Websocket link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, hasura, vue-apollo

Been trying to get a Subscription working with Hasura and Vue Apollo with a websocket link with Vue Apollo with Vue3. Have it all seemingly setup.

The subscription works in Hasura so that’s right.

The query version worked with the HTTP link.

So the WS Link for some reason is just not working it. It seems like it might be authentication I’m not passing in correctly for some reason?

```
import './tailwind.css'
import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes.js'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
import { split } from 'apollo-link'
import { WebSocketLink } from 'apollo-link-ws'
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'


const token = localStorage.getItem('Auth_token')


// HTTP connection to the API
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  // You should use an absolute URL here
  uri: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX.hasura.app/v1/graphql',
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-hasura-admin-secret": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
})

// Create the subscription websocket link
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: 'ws://XXXXXXXXXXX.hasura.app/v1/graphql',
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    inactivityTimeout: 30000,
    lazy: true,
  },
  connectionParams: {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      // "x-hasura-admin-secret": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
    }
}
})


// using the ability to split links, you can send data to each link
// depending on what kind of operation is being sent
const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const definition = getMainDefinition(query)
    return definition.kind === 'OperationDefinition' &&
      definition.operation === 'subscription'
  },
  wsLink,
  httpLink
)


// Cache implementation
const cache = new InMemoryCache()

// Create the apollo client
const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache,
  connectToDevTools: true,
})

const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },

  render: () => h(App),
})

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
})

// router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
//   console.log("it's here", this.$auth0)
//   // if (
//   //   // make sure the user is authenticated
//   // ) {
//   //   // redirect the user to the login page
    
//   // }
// })

app.use(router)
app.use(
  createAuth0({
    domain: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
    client_id: "JgajoigAywNqoIyvQWNJjpq6TS3g5Ljn",
    // redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/the-clouds"
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin
  })
);
app.mount('#app')
```

[Main.JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrAvV.png)

[subscription working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbLbk.png)

[subscription in vue apollo front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32O1t.png)

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPjz.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBGon.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Was headers setup wrong. Wooh!

```js
// Create the subscription websocket link
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: 'ws://XXXXX-backend.hasura.app/v1/graphql',
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    inactivityTimeout: 30000,
    lazy: true,
    connectionParams: {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-hasura-admin-secret": "XXXXX",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
}
  },

})
```

Comment: Hello friend, you don't want to expose your admin secret in the frontend, you should just need to send the JWT token

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I did try without the admin secret though and both failed to authorize. So maybe my Hasura setup isn't correct in some way to mean it's needed.

Comment: Check that your JWT token is valid